# Type 'MyComponent' already defines a member called 'BuildRenderTree' with the same parameter types

Tags: blazor, components, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

This is what I have - almost the simplest possible Blazor (.NET 6.0, server side) component:

```
@this.Title

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "h1");
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

All my efforts to make it compile gives me the following:
`error CS0111: Type 'MyComponent' already defines a member called 'BuildRenderTree' with the same parameter types`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In a Razor file the content defined like this is compiled by the Razor Compiler into a `BuildRenderTree` override method.

When you also define one like this:

```cs
@this.Title
```

The resultant class has two `BuildRenderTree` methods and thus errors as you have shown.

What are you trying to achieve?

You can re-write your code like this:

```cs
public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string? Title { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "h1");
        builder.AddContent(2, this.Title);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. [EditorRequired] has no impact on the error (and why should it?!)
2. Overrding a method not meant to be overriden is a sure sign of a bad design IMHO
3. I need to achieve exactly what the code snippet does, that is, to wrap component's content within a tag. In other words - component -> <tag>component</tag>.

Comment: "Overriding a method not meant to be overridden is a sure sign of a bad design IMHO".  A method marked as `virtual` is designed to be overridden.  Every time you compile components, the Razor compiler overrides `BuildRenderTree`.  [Polite] IMHO may be a little astray here.

Comment: In the inheritance scenario the generated BuildRenderTree should at lease invoke the inherited one - base.BuildRenderTree(builder), Even this is not possible. And this is the only thing which happen to be generated if the component is completely empty (void). Looks like I'm missing the point...

Comment: "I need to achieve exactly what the code snippet does,"?  Your code isn't quite as clear as you believe it is.  @HH also agrees - "So what exactly do you want to accomplish? ".  Both of us answer a lot of Blazor questions on here so we aren't amateurs.

Comment: Inheritance doesn't stipulate that you must call the base.  Many people call `base.OnInitiliazedAsync` in their overridden versions.  The base just returns a completed task: so a pointless execise!  I agree with you that `ComponentBase` pushes some of the *SOLID* boundaries.

Comment: My last comment (and I consider the topic closed since I saw the generated output, anyway thanks for your time!) - once a method is intended to be overriden by the compiler (only!) thus discarding any of my changes than this is not  good design. Definitely! And second, it's a very long answer to explain what I want to achieve - I abstracted it with content -> <tag>content</tag>. In this particular case tag is H1 but maybe anything. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: So back to the real question - what are you trying to achieve?  Are you looking for a wrapper component.  Define some wrapper content in a parent and the wrap the content on the parent in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254328/discussion-between-alexander-christov-and-mrc-aka-shaun-curtis).